# Windows 7 customize folder type - sort type

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have 2 folders customized as "General Items". Below is how I configured:

- Right click on folder
- Property > customized tab > select "General Items" in optimized this folder for

Both folder is sorted by date modified. One of the folder has the order:

```
file1, date modified=7/1/2011
file2, date modified=6/1/2011
folder1, date modified=7/1/2011
folder2, date modified=6/1/2011
```

However, the other folder looks like:

```
folder1, date modified=7/1/2011
folder2, date modified=6/1/2011
file1, date modified=7/1/2011
file2, date modified=6/1/2011
```

What could cause one has all files on top half, while the other folder has all folders on top half? I want make both folder have files on top half. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have secondary sorting (by type) active.

To change it (works fine for me):

- Make "Details" view first (obviously)
- Sort by name (click on "Name" column)
- Now sort by "Date modified" (click on appropriate column)

The above sequence results in files first then folders.

If you Shift+Click on "Type" column, it will sort Folders first and then Files.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But this didn't work for me though. I found a workaround by changing folder type to "Documents" instead of "General Items".